# Can my Facebook App programatically subscribe to real-time-updates on multiple Page/User profiles?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to get notified programatically (using the callback URL) that any one of 100 Facebook Pages (or a User, but less important) has posted a new post to their Timeline/Feed or edited some of the Page details such as opening times for example.

My understanding from reading this documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.3 is that I can "Subscribe" to changes programatically for multiple Objects (i.e. 50 Pages and 100 Users) using my App providing i have Permissions to do so from the User (I only want publicly available Page data).

I don't see the value in this "Subscribe" functionality if it does not do what the above requirements describes

Update: I have edited the question slightly as the initial question was found to be a bug in the Facebook user documentation as discovered by the comment below.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_2_new_features

There is a new endpoint called [subscribed_apps](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/subscribed_apps) - you can connect an App to a Page without adding it as Tab now, so it does not show up for the users. The rest is the same, you still need /subscriptions to add a subscription (with callback and object) - but there is a bug in the docs, it´s not removed in v2.3: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/799294656844725/

Btw, of course you can´t subscribe to a Page you don´t own. You have to be Moderator at least.

Comment: That appears to show what Apps are subscribed to "My Page" rather than what Pages i am subscribed to using "My App"? I want to be able to subscribe from "My App" to  1 or many Pages. Is that possible (also without being a moderator on the Page)?

Comment: sorry, i just used the realtime api in a new app and did not understand it correctly before. i will edit my answer.

Comment: Why would i not be allowed to subscribe using my app with real-time-updates to a Page which is publicly available?

Comment: It just isn’t. You need a page access token to subscribe to updates from a page.

Comment: I tried to add the app to the page through the [link](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=[APPID]&redirect_uri=[redirectURL]) but the realtime updates are not sent, is it a must that the tab should be added through the api edge?